# Dual boot with windows 7!

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I'm using windows 7 right now. I want to install Ubuntu with dual boot. Is is safe? And does the process go safely?

Comment: Yes it safe.  Take a look at [Windows Dual Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: Try (rather than install) Ubuntu **12.04.2 LTS** first, before anything more adventurous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to have Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 7. I have them both running safely.
More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe.But please keep a backup of your windows in case if something goes wrong.
Make sure that you do not play with partitioning.
Watch this video for instructions :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C7yINJQKW0
Yes, you are.

Comment: I'm following this link! M i on the right path?http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: But make sure that you have back up

Comment: okay! :) thanks! i will tell you when I'm done! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a backup of your documents, media files, and other key settings ..

then you should **NOT** proceed ..

---

***But, with that caveat, it is quite safe.***

Comment: I have backup! :)